# how to store image or file in a folder and that path in Database using php but image or file is not coming from post functionality of html

Tags: php, iphone, ios

Here my Problem is:

`Iphone` developers sends me an image or `.doc` or `.pdf` or etc....files to me to store in Database using services

So I directly tried to store them in Database but problem is if they send me a file of 1MB then am unable to store it in Database due to its size so i am thinking to save that uploaded file of `iphone` into a folder and save that path in Database...

I know how to store the image in folder coming from post functionality but am new to this functionality so can you help me to fix this problem......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here am Decoding the image coming from IPhone....

```
 $imgdata = base64_decode($child);

 $f = finfo_open();
```

Here am knowing the type of file coming from IPhone

```
 $mime_type = finfo_buffer($f,$imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

 $i = strpos($mime_type,'/');
 $type = substr($mime_type,$i+1);
```

Here am saving the file name as time() value....

```
 $Image1=time().'.'.$type;
```

Here am saving that file in a Folder named files....

```
 file_put_contents('files/'.$Image1,$imgdata);

 $Image='files/'.time().'.'.$type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal data is retrieved using the `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables. Uploaded files are accessed with the `$_FILES` variable. In the `$_FILES` is the name which you can retrieve to store in the database.

Comment: $_FILES contains parameters na like $_FILES['image']['name']; in ['image'] here image is the name given using html input tag na so here how can i use this?

Comment: INSERT INTO table SET filename=$_FILES['image']['name'] etc

Comment: am not asking the query actually here am getting direct image as $image so how can i use $_FILES['image']['name'] to seperate the image name?

Comment: I think you better read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php as the example I gave you showed you how to access the filename.

Answer (score 0):

for upload the image in specified folde,use this:

```
if($_FILES["file"]["name"]!="")
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/portfolio/presentation/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);  
}
```

and then mysql query.and if you want to check the file then you may use this:

```
function chk_image($imgname,$imgtype,$imgerr)
{
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $imgname));
$err = '';

if ((($imgtype == "image/gif") || ($imgtype == "image/jpeg") || ($imgtype == "image/png")|| ($imgtype == "image/pjpeg")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    if ($imgerr > 0)
    {
        $err = "Invalid file";
    }
}
else
{
    $err = "Invalid file (Please attach only image file).";
}

return $err;
}
```